# Ways for managing the installation and configuration of various software applications and settings in linux?

Tags: linux, scripting, configuration-management, automated-install

What are some ways for managing the installation and configuration of various software applications and settings in group of linux development and server computers? Is a set of basic scripts a good means of attack?

I was thinking about just having a ton of scripts, such as:

```
setup_dev_env [install|uninstall|reinstall]
setup_nfs [...]
setup_nfs_share [...]
setup_http [...]
setup_memcache_node [...]
```

Is there any better method?

It would be nice to be able to "upgrade" an installation script too, for example, to change common development settings.

Comment: A little bit of background would be helpful.

Comment: What kind of background would be of benefit? I'd like to use the solution for setting up development computers and web-related server nodes.

Comment: How many? 1? 3? 300? Standalone, networked, or clustered?

Comment: Less than 20 networked. I'd like to easily set up any number of VM instances with various capabilities.

Comment: I'm currently using Ubuntu if that is of any relevance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for configuration management, there are many options out there. A couple are:

- [Puppet](http://www.puppetlabs.com/)
- [CF Engine](http://www.cfengine.org/)
- If you're on RedHat or CentOS [RHN Sattelite](http://www.redhat.com/red_hat_network/) or [SpaceWalk](http://www.redhat.com/spacewalk/) respectivly

Answer (score 1):

Other options are Chef and Bcfg2. However, Puppet is the one with the most mind share right now.

If you go the Puppet route, you should try using either [Foreman](http://theforeman.org/projects/foreman/wiki/Screenshots)  or [PuppetDashboard](http://github.com/reductivelabs/puppet-dashboard)
so that you can have a more manageable Puppet installation.